# Orthogonality of two directional derivatives

Tags: geometry

I was told in General Relativity lectures that mathematically strictly speaking, *directional derivatives* and *vectors* are equivalent.

Then I am left wondering if directional derivatives can be orthogonal? If indeed yes, then what exactly does that means? Furthermore, is there any intuitive explanation for two directional derivative to be orthogonal? If the answer is no, then why? Aren't they supposed to be strictly equivalent?

Would anyone be kind enough to elaborate to me?

Comment: This is imprecise; I would say "tangent vectors." Yes, they can be orthogonal, it means that the corresponding tangent vectors are orthogonal.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks for your comment! Is there anything fun (or properties we can directly take advantage of) with orthogonal directional derivatives?

Comment: Nothing I can think of that wouldn't be conceptually simpler to describe using tangent vectors.